# Typescript - compile async/await without generator shim

Tags: typescript, async-await, generator

Targeting `ES6` in tsconfig.json, `tsc` emits the below generator shim.

```
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
    function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
    function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
    function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
    step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
});
};
```

Is it possible to tell `tsc` not to emit this shim while maintaining the ES6 target?

Comment: Have you tried to change the `target` property to most recent one ?

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough. I've updated it but I want async/await to still be transpiled to generators but without the shim.

Answer (score 0):

`async`/`await` is a ES 2017 feature. If you don't want the shim, set your target to `es2017` in your `tsconfig`